# Platform specific MONOTONIC clock problems

Tags: c, rust, clock

I am porting [this C library](https://github.com/victorfisac/Physac/blob/master/src/physac.h) to Rust

It has a sort of timer logic:

```c
PHYSACDEF void InitTimer(void)
{
    #if defined(_WIN32)
        QueryPerformanceFrequency((unsigned long long int *) &frequency);
    #endif

    #if defined(__linux__)
        struct timespec now;
        if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now) == 0)
            frequency = 1000000000;
    #endif

    #if defined(__APPLE__)
        mach_timebase_info_data_t timebase;
        mach_timebase_info(&timebase);
        frequency = (timebase.denom*1e9)/timebase.numer;
    #endif

    baseTime = GetTimeCount();      // Get MONOTONIC clock time offset
    startTime = GetCurrentTime();   // Get current time
}
```

This function seems to be initializing 3 timer variables: `baseTime`, `startTime`, `frequency`.
For windows the code is clear, for the `__APPLE__` platform it does something that makes sense too, but for linux it is just checking if `clok_gettime(...)` doesn't fail and setting frequency to 1000000000.

Next let's look at GetTimeCount():

```c
static uint64_t GetTimeCount(void)
{
    uint64_t value = 0;

    #if defined(_WIN32)
        QueryPerformanceCounter((unsigned long long int *) &value);
    #endif

    #if defined(__linux__)
        struct timespec now;
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now);
        value = (uint64_t)now.tv_sec*(uint64_t)1000000000 + (uint64_t)now.tv_nsec;
    #endif

    #if defined(__APPLE__)
        value = mach_absolute_time();
    #endif

    return value;
}
```

Yet again, it does something that makes sense on windows and macos, but for linux it multiplies `now.tv_sec` with the `1000000000` value, converting the value into nanoseconds.

And now, GetCurrentTime():

```c
static double GetCurrentTime(void)
{
    return (double)(GetTimeCount() - baseTime)/frequency*1000;
}
```

Makes enough sense at a first glance, but frequency is initialized with 0 when declared so if the operation on linux fails, it will crash because there will be a division by zero (at least that's what i think).
[EDIT]: The operation on linux can't fail, since MONOTONIC_CLOCK can't fail. It is the time since boot, so it can't fail.

Does Rust provide a tool that looks like the MacOS or windows solution so i can use it to initialize those values instead?
Can i use `std::time::Instant` to replace the variables or should i use it in another way?
If there is no Rust universal tool, should i do platform specific code:

```rust
#[cfg(target_os = "windows")]
// winapi crate code here
```

Comment: `frequency = 1000000000;`.  That is not 0.  Maybe the code just forgets to call InitTimer().

Comment: @HansPassant the code runs ok, but frequency is initialized at the top of the header with 0. That is what i meant.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the C library, which hasn't been observed because `clock_gettime` never fails in practice, so `frequency` ends up always being initialized. As for your question, yes `Instant` and `Duration` are there to provide similar functionality in a portable way.